# Copy rows a set number of times via a formula

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a delivery manifest that shows the amount of products coming in, descriptions etc. that we use to produce barcode labels. Unfortunately the barcode software we use means that we need to duplicate the information in rows for the amount of items we have- for example if we are due in 12 iPads we must replicate the rows 12 times - is there any way I can link the 'number due in' column to replicate the data for me?

I need a formula, or multiple formulas, not a macro. I've searched the internet for a solution.  Lots of macros, but no formulas so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got something for you.  Made this in Excel 2013, but I don't think there's anything here that would cause problems for 2007 or 2010.

https://app.box.com/s/zd13xmkge25k3jh5028p

On the 'ShortList' sheet, you can enter an Item, Description and the number of Units for that item.  An 'Item ID' field is auto-generated for each entry added.

The 'Expanded' sheet spreads it all out, all four columns are generated based on entries on the 'ShortList'.

All of the formulas have been coded to disappear until needed, so you can drag them down for as many rows as you think you might need ahead of time.

Hope this helps!